# Traveling from JNB to DUB through IST

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, short-connections, isl, dub

I will be traveling from JNB to DUB with a layover in Istanbul. All my flights will be on Turkish Airlines. Is 2 hours and 15 minutes enough time in Istanbul to make my connecting flight? Do I have to go through any extra security or is my flight from IST to DUB still considered international?

Comment: Really a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108198/transit-time-required-in-istanbul-airport, but because that has no upvoted answers it wont let me mark it as such

Comment: Istanbul and Dubai being in two different countries, yes, it's an international flight...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's in one booking, you will go through a security check in IST, but nothing else.

2 hours and 15 minutes should be enough, provided the flight from JNB isn't awfully delayed, but even if it is, you'll be re-booked onto the next flight.